# print a std::vector of std::tuple with BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTION in Boost.Test

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-test

Hello I'm trying to use `Boost.Test` for my unit tests.  However some of my functions return a collection of tuples, in a `std::vector< std::tuple< TypeA, TypeB > >`.

To work with `BOOST_CHECK_EQUALS` and `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTION`, I specialized `boost::test_tools::print_log_value` to print nice tuples and vectors as [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976130/boost-check-equal-with-pairint-int-and-custom-operator) explains.  I also provide `operator<<` for tuples, so that my vector can use that while printing the whole vector.  For cleanness this operator lies in the blank namespace.

However the compilation fails, as the implementation of `boost::test_tools::print_log_value` `<std::vector<std::tuple<...>>>` cannot find the `operator<<` for tuples.

Here is a minimal code which is, sorry, already quite verbose.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE my_test
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

/////////////////
// std::vector //
/////////////////

// boost printing method
namespace boost {
namespace test_tools {
template< typename Type >
struct print_log_value< std::vector< Type > > {
    void operator()( std::ostream& s, const std::vector< Type > &collection ) {
        const int size = collection.size();

        if( size == 0 ) {
            s << "[]";
        }
        else {
            s << "[ ";
            for( int i =0; i <= size-2; ++i ) {
                s << collection[i] << ", ";
            }
            s << collection[size-1] << " ]";
        }
        return s;
    }
};
} //namespace test_tools
} //namespace boost

////////////////
// std::tuple //
////////////////

// recursive calls for printing
namespace tuple_print_aux{

    template< int I, int J, typename... Types >
    struct recursive_printer {
        static void print( std::ostream& s, const std::tuple<Types...> &collection ) {
            s << std::get< I >( collection ) << ", ";
            recursive_printer< I+1, J-1, Types... >::print( s, collection );
        }
    };

    template< int I, typename... Types >
    struct recursive_printer< I, 1, Types... > {
        static void print( std::ostream& s, const std::tuple<Types...> &collection ) {
            s << std::get< I >( collection );
        }
    };

    template< typename... Types >
    void recursive_print( std::ostream& s, const std::tuple<Types...> &collection ) {
        recursive_printer< 0, sizeof...(Types), Types... >::print( s, collection );
    }
}

// output stream operator
template< typename... Types >
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& s, const std::tuple<Types...> &collection ) {
    s << "( ";
    tuple_print_aux::recursive_print< Types... >( s, collection );
    s << " )";
    return s;
}

// boost printing method
namespace boost {
namespace test_tools {
template< typename... Types >
struct print_log_value< std::tuple< Types... > > {
    void operator()( std::ostream& s, const std::tuple<Types...> &collection ) {
        s << "( ";
        tuple_print_aux::recursive_print< Types... >( s, collection );
        s << " )";
    }
};
} //namespace test_tools
} //namespace boost

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test_case) {
    //builds successfully
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( std::make_tuple(1,"a"), std::make_tuple(1,"a") );

    //builds successfully
    std::vector< int > v( 2, 3 ), w( 2, 7 );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS( v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin(), w.end() );

    //fails to build
    std::vector< std::tuple<int,int> > a( 1, std::make_tuple(1,3) ), b( 1, std::make_tuple(2,2) );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end() );
};
```

Of course, putting the `operator<<` for `std::tuple`s into the `std` namespace solve the problem, but this is a non-standard non-elegant solution.
So... how should I approach the problem. ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried putting `using namespace tuple_print_aux;` before the test case?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should declare

```
template< typename... Types >
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& s, const std::tuple<Types...> &collection )
```

before the `struct print_log_value< std::vector< Type > >`. Also I think that the specialization of `struct print_log_value` for **tuples** is enough as the `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS` do not actually see the `std::vector` but an iterator on it.