# How to select a namespace to which to add a specialization

Tags: c++

I am trying to add a specialization to a namespace owned by library 1 for a type in a namespace owned by library 2.  For example, in order to use BOOST TEST for std::pair, I have to add

```
template<class T, class S>   
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::pair<T,S>& p)
```

to `std` or `boost::test_tools::tt_detail`.

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std), extending `std` is not allowed except in a few situations which my problem doesn't seem to fall into.  The remaining choice is 
to extend `boost::test_tools::tt_detail`.  The need to extend a details namespace seems awkward.

Is there anything else that could be done or what should be done in general?

[Edit]

This problem is more than surrounding code in some namespace.  Many libraries like to use this technique to let users provide read/write handler for custom types.  For example, boost's json library relies on `operator>>`.  My updated question is, what happens if I'd like to use different implementation for different purpose?

Comment: You need to use `tt_detail`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976130/boost-check-equal-with-pairint-int-and-custom-operator

Comment: @AndyG I updated my question